# Ask some work to be assigned to someone in office

Tags: phrase-request

Usually I used to write this as:

> "Please allocate a resource to do this task"

I'm sick of this sentence which is used by everyone in our office and it had become very common in emails. So, no one cares about those emails except the recipient. Therefore I would like to alternative way of writing this.

Comment: *Could you please have somebody take care of this?*

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should check out for synonyms, here are some example sentences:

"Please allocate a resource to do this task"

"Put someone in charge of that task"

"Please designate a person to this task"